# How can I update a "rank" column's values based on the values of another column?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database table `GOALS_SCORED` with columns `gender`, `goalRank` and `numGoalsScored`.

The `numGoalsScored` is set, but I want to set the `goalRank` *PER GENDER* to 1, 2, 3, etc.

So I want 2 values that are `goalRank` 1 (for M and F). Just for now, assume that no 2 boys have the same # of goals, same for girls.  What's the SQL to update that column with the right values?

Comment: You may want to post a relevant sample data with the expected result.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you'd 'store' as such, but rather calculate 'on-the-fly'

Comment: I hear you, but I want to store it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE goals_scored SET goalRank = (
  SELECT count(*) FROM goals_scored AS i WHERE 
    i.numGoalsScored > goals_scored.numGoalsScored AND
    i.gender = goals_scored.gender
) + 1;
```

is one way. O(n^2) though.